# Определить, является ли символ цифрой или буквой

Tags: c++

Написать функцию, которая возвращает истину,
если переданный параметр является алфавитно-цифровым и ложь, если не является.

```
if( a == (0 - 9 ) || ( A - Z))
```

Как сделать так чтобы он читал и понял что это за символ поправьте плз

Comment: "Если бы я хоть разок прочел про глаз!" Виктор Голявкин "Я жду вас всегда с интересом"

Comment: не понял вас) что это значит?

Comment: `if (isalnum(a))`  :)

Comment: нет, нужно именно так как я показал

Comment: [0-9A-Za-z]+ . Вот тебе Regexp. Дальше -> Google

Comment: @icYFTL, в данной задаче можно обойтись без использования регулярных выражений.

Comment: @isnullxbh, я прекрасно это понимаю, но судя по комментариям -> ему нужен именно регекс стайл

Comment: @icYFTL, не уверен. Если я правильно понял, ТС просто не может использовать библиотечные функции.

Comment: @Саша, измените заголовок так, чтобы он отражал суть проблемы. В противном случае, еще немного - и Ваш вопрос закроют. Что касается кода - посмотрите таблицу ASCII символов, посмотрите в каких диапазонах находятся цифры и буквы (как в low-case, так и в upper-case) - и проверяйте на вхождение `a` в эти диапазоны.

Comment: `если переданный параметр является...` параметр это что? Символ? Строка? или wide символ или строка?

Comment: @Саша если так как вы показали, то `if (('0' <= a && a <= '9') || a == 'a' || a == 'A')` и так далее для оставшихся символов алфавита

Comment: спасибо, учту))

Comment: Вы бы, когда человеку отвечаете, писали @ с его именем - так он получит уведомление, что к нему обратились...

Comment: @ isnullxbh спасибо, учту)

Answer (score 3):

если не пользоваться стандартными средствами можно написать так, если конечно передаваемый параметр является простым char

```
bool isAlphaOrDigit(const char symb)
{
  return symb >= '0' && symb <= '9' || 
    symb >= 'a' && symb <= 'z' || 
    symb >= 'A' && symb <= 'Z';
}
```

**Update:**

прошлый алгоритм не является переносимым, поскольку стандарт не гарантирует, что набор символов в кодировке содержит буквы латинского алфавита в определенном порядке.

вот версия, которая является более переносимой:

```
bool isAlphaOrDigit(const char symb)
{
  return symb >= '0' && symb <= '9' ||
    symb == 'a' || symb == 'b' || /*... ||*/ symb == 'z' ||
    symb == 'A' || symb == 'B' || /*... ||*/ symb == 'Z';
}
```

Comment: Впрочем, если передаваемый символ будет типа `int` (как в `isalnum()` из `<ctype.h>`), то все также будет работать

Comment: Для букв не определен порядок, так что `symb >= 'a' && symb <= 'z'` не обязан работать.

Comment: @вася хмм, мне казалось в большинстве кодировок английские буквы подряд идут

Comment: @Ildar если вам достаточно правильности ответа для большинства, а не для всех случаев, то ок. Думаю, стоит указать это в ответе как минимум.

Comment: @вася да как раз хочу обновить